# sys.schemas not avalable in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am not being able to find an alternative for sys.schemas in postgresql. sys.schemas is available in sql server. I am new to postgres and currently migrating from sql server to postgresql. Kindly help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `\dn` metacommand in `psql` and `pg_catalog.pg_namespace`

Answer (score 2):

`pg_catalog.pg_namespace` [would be it](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-namespace.html).

Or you can use `\dn` [metacommand](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) in `psql`

Comment: or: information_schema (which is barely usable, but it is ANSI)